# Sencha bug tracker url

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-cmd, bug-tracker

Can anyone give me the sencha bug tracker url. I have to check one bug's status. I am facing an issue which I found in sencha blog also and found it was added in bug tracker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no bug tracker.  It's internal to sencha.  You can track bugs in the bug forum if it has been reported.

http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?80-Ext-Bugs